# Show that ($R^\times$, $\cdot$) is a group.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

($R$,+,$\cdot$) is a ring with 1. We define $R^\times$ := { r $\in$ R : r is invertible with respect to multiplication}.

(i) Show that ($R^\times$, $\cdot$) is a group ( the so called uniform-group of $R$). Uniform group definition: The uniform-group from a ring with 1 is defined as the set of all multiplicative inverse elements).

(ii) Let $K$ be a field. Find $K^\times$. My solution: (i) $R^\times$ := { r $\in$ R : r is invertible with respect to multiplication} $\Rightarrow$ $\exists$ r$^{-1}$ $\cdot$ r = 1 = r $\cdot$ r$^{-1}$. Let *r, s, t* $\in$ $R^\times$ s.t there exists *$\tilde{r}$, $\tilde{s}$, $\tilde{t}$* $\in$ $R$. r$\cdot$$\tilde{r}$ = $\tilde{r}$$\cdot$r = s$\cdot$$\tilde{s}$ = $\tilde{s}$$\cdot$s = t$\cdot$$\tilde{t}$ = $\tilde{t}$$\cdot$t = 1. Furthermore, we have 1 $\in$ $R^\times$ and for r $\in$ $R^\times$ is $\tilde{r}$ an inverse element.

My idea was to create enough elements to prove that those elements fulfil the group axioms. (*closure under multiplication, associativity, identity element and inverse element*)

(ii) I honestly don't know what I really need to prove or show here but I came up with this solution so far: $K^\times$ := {k $\in$ K : k is invertible with respect to the multiplication and addition}.

I think that my solutions are wrong and I don't know how to continue at this point. Any hints guiding to the right direction I very much appreciate.

Comment: Read your solution out loud: "$R^\times$ is, by item (i), the set of all elements of $r$ which are invertible with respect to multiplication. This implies that there exists the inverse of $r$ multiplied by $r$ is equal to $1$, which in turn is equal to $r$ times the inverse of $r$." Doesn't make sense, which should point out that this is not going too well...

Comment: Any question that says  "show that A is a B" is trying to see if you understand the definition of a B.  Look up the definition of a B.  Here you need to verify the group axioms.  You know multiplication is associative, so that is easy.  Is there an identity?  Are there inverses? You haven't defined what $A^\times$ is based on $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from associativity (which you already have for free because $(R,+\cdot)$ is a ring), none of the group axioms require three elements. What are you trying to prove with $r,s$ and $t$? Also "create enough elements" is irrelevant. There are groups with very few elements (all the way down to a single element), so as long as you have $1$, and show that that's the identity element, you don't need *more elements*. You just need that for all elements you *can* find, the corresponding products and inverses also exist.

1. Closure: show that if $r$ and $s$ are both invertible, then $rs$ is invertible too (construct the inverse of $rs$ using the inverses of $r$ and $s$)
2. Associativity we get for free
3. Identity element. Show that $1$ fulfills the requirement for the identity element
4. Inverses. Show that if $r$ is invertible, then so is $r^{-1}$ (what is $(r^{-1})^{-1}$?)

Answer (score 0):

Just stay calm and look at the definitions:

> **Definition**: $R^\times=\left\{r\in R:r\text{ is invertible with respect to multiplication}\right\}$.

In (ii), we are taking a particular case: $R=K$ is a *field*

Look at the definitions again: What is special about a field?

> **Definition**: A *field* $K$ is a commutative ring with unit such that every $r\neq 0$ has a multiplicative inverse. (And we usually also assume that $0\neq 1$.)

Ok, so item (ii) is asking: Find $K^\times$ if $K$ is a field.

Look at the definitions and the answer shouldn't be hard. Think about a particular case if it makes it easier to visualize: what if $K=\mathbb{Q}$? $\mathbb{R}$?..